# symfony2. hot to use transchoice with expression

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation, twig-extension

Trying to do in symfony something like

```
{% transchoice count %}
{%count% mod 2 == 0} %count% - even page|{%count% mod 2 == 1} %count% - odd page
{% endtranschoice %}
```

ofc that is just example - thinking of, how i can put an expression into transchoice?

Comment: I think you need to move the dedicated logic outside the translation and translate only the consequently label